# Converting a map stored in hiddenput to JSON in JS

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags, hidden-field

I am storing a Hashmap in JSP in a hiddeninput element

How can I parse it into a JSON object in my javascript??

When i print the hidden input variable value in my JS output is something like this:

```
{zipcode=560036, fmid=xyz, quantity=1}
```

Comment: Probably you need a JS object. Store the value in JSON format, it is easy to convert to a JS object.

Comment: is that contains also nested objects/arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to pass a `JSON string` from server so you can easily parse. If you have a simple object structure like this (your example) you can try split it and take eack key/value pair. here is a example

```js
var mapAsStr = "{zipcode=560036, fmid=xyz, quantity=1}";
var convertToObj = function(str) {
    var obj = {};
    str.replace(/\{|\}/g, '').split(',').forEach(function(pair) {
        var keyVal = pair.split("=");
        var key = keyVal[0].trim();
        var val = keyVal[1].trim();
        val = isNaN(val) ? val : parseFloat(val);
        obj[key] = val;
    });
    return obj;
}
console.log(convertToObj(mapAsStr));
```

But note you can proceed with this only if you have a flat object structure with primitive values.

Comment: Hi this works, but I have one question: What does this do? "str.replace(/\{|\}/g, '')" . Also why are we parsing the val to float?: "parseFloat(val);"

Comment: And what do you mean by "this only if you have a flat object structure with primitive values"? I am setting a HashMap in my JSP and this maP will always be like as given the question. I dont understand what you mean by primitive values here, these can be anything right?

Comment: @user2696258 `str.replace(/\{|\}/g, '')` is for removing the starting `{` and ending `}` from the string and then basically splitting the dtring by `,` and then splitting each tokens by `=` to get `key` & `value` pair. Flat structure meant all of your keys will captains primitive value, and not nested objects. in that case this logic wont work as those keys will contains `{` in values

Comment: Also why are we parsing the val to float?: "parseFloat(val);" IF we wont do this, then value which are numbers will remain strings right?